# MVC4 - TryValidateModel breaks unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, mvccontrib

I have the following controller method

```
    public ActionResult Create(Category category)
    {
        //default values
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(category.GeoAreaLevelIdentifier))
        {
            category.GeoAreaLevelIdentifier = "OutputArea";
        }                
        category.CreatorIdentifier = EsdContext.User.UniqueIdentifier.ToString();            
        category.Created = DateTime.Now;

        //validation
        RevalidateModel(category);

        new CategoryBroker().Create(category);
        return JsonNow(category);
    }
```

which fills some default values to the model and THEN validates it. This is because the client code is allowed to submit a model without some of the required fields. The missing fields are filled by the controller (see above).

RevalidateModel method calls TryValidateModel:

```
    protected void RevalidateModel(object model)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        TryValidateModel(model); //called explicitly since model has been updated
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //error message
        }
    }
```

But when I call Create method from a unit test, it fails because TryValidateModel expects controllerContext:

```
     Value cannot be null.Parameter name: controllerContext
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?
Should I create the controllerContext eg by MvcContrib TestHelper?

Comment: Yes, you need to mock up the controller context to call this method from a unit test.

Comment: @mayabelle  " you need to mock up the controller context" - do you know the best way to do it? Have you tried MvcContrib.TestHelper?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332060/how-do-i-unit-test-actions-without-mocking-that-use-updatemodel

Answer (score 0):

In this case

```
using Moq;
.........
        readonly MockRepository _mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);
.........
        controller.ControllerContext = _mockRepository.Create<ControllerContext>().Object;
```

works good enough.

Best.

Comment: It is perfectly ok to mock the ControllerContext - so the test in the question would work without exception. I use it also a lot and wonder why this answer was down voted ...